# How to insert on first time and update for the second time

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, insert-update

I want to insert the row if it's a first entry of the day else I want to update the row..How can I do that..Currently I had done for update and don't know how to do it for insert..Please help me to achieve this..

This is my controller code:

```
$startdate = $this->input->post('TDate');
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
$data1 = array(
        'tdate'=>$newDate,
        'total_credit'=>$total_credit['amount'],
        'total_debit'=>$total_debit['amount'],
       );
$this->db->where('tdate',$newDate);
$this->db->update('daytot',$data1);
```

Comment: Can you add some more data and logic to what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I am having a table name daytot there i want to insert if it's a first entry on a date otherwise i want to update..I have done for update but i don't know how to do it insert:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below one

```
$newDate   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post('TDate')));
$data1     = array(
    'tdate'        => $newDate,
    'total_credit' => $total_credit['amount'],
    'total_debit'  => $total_debit['amount'],
);

//Check record is exist for the request date
$objQuery = $this->db->get_where('daytot', array('tdate' => $newDate));
if ($objQuery->num_rows() > 0) { //UPDATE
    $this->db->where('tdate', $newDate);
    $this->db->update('daytot', $data1);
}
else { //INSERT
    $this->db->insert('daytot', $data1);
}
```

Hope this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem, which you may find acceptable, would be to just *always* insert your transactional data as it comes along.  That is, the first record and every subsequent record would come into the database as a separate insert.  Then, if you needed to do any reporting, e.g. by hour or day, you could simply hit the table of transactions and aggregate.

The problem you are trying to solve, namely conditionally doing an insert at the start of a day, is troublesome, because in addition to what you already pointed out, you might also have to worry about multi nodes in your application trying to do this at the same time.

Comment: i want that aggrgate function to be saved on a seperate table daytot total_credit and total_debit are the result of the aggregate functions

Comment: I recommend _against_ storing your aggregates, since they are really just deviates of the original data.  Make your life easier if possible.  I don't see your request coming up very often in real life.